# Dropdown Menu Working in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: html, css

I made a dropdown menu and it works perfect in safari, however when I open it up in chrome i can't see the dropdown when I hover over the link. Why is this? I obviously need it to work in both browsers for compatibility reasons.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 6vw;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1.7vw;
}

p1 {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.header {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit- sticky;
  background-color: #DF744A;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.main-nav li a,
.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.2em 2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFAE89;
}

li.products {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #DF744A;
  min-width: 8vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.products:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.mainbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.updates {
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: #FEDCD2;
}

.section-1 {
  flex: 80%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #bfd8d2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.bands {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Elle and Belle Design</h1>
  <p1>Bespoke Handmade Headbands and Accessories</p>
</div>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="products">
      <a href="products.html" class="dropdown">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="headbands.html">Headbands</a>
        <a href="earrings.html">Earrings</a>
        <a href="Other.html">Other</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="mainbody">

  <div class="updates">
    <h3>Updates</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section-1">
    <div class="bands">
      <img src="oliviaband.jpg" alt="Olivia Band" width="330" height="400">
      <img src="goldband.jpg" alt="Gold Band" width="330" height="400">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, you have a `<p1>` element

Comment: Hi, Just out of curiosity, what is wrong with a p1 element?

Comment: Well for starters, there is no such thing. There's `<p>` and there's `<h1>` but there's no `<p1>`

Comment: How would I go about using different styles on p elements if I did not number them?

Comment: You could give them unique IDs. Or one or more classes. But you shouldn't just randomly make up your own elements.

Comment: Okay, thankyou for this. I'm new to it and learning it on my own so thats useful.

Answer (score 2):

Few points:

1. `.main-nav ul` had `overflow: hidden` which was hiding `.dropdown-content` which overflows the `ul`.
2. `li.products` was missing `position: relative` this stops your `.dropdown-content` `position: absolute` spanning full browser width.
3. `.dropdown-content` I added `left: 0` and `right: 0` so it uses the width of the `position: relative` (`li.products`) parent.

I've updated your code in the below snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 6vw;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1.7vw;
}

p1 {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.header {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}


/* This had overflow: hidden; */

.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit- sticky;
  background-color: #DF744A;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.main-nav li a,
.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.2em 2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFAE89;
}


/* Requires position: relative;*/

li.products {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #DF744A;
  min-width: 8vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.products:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.mainbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.updates {
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: #FEDCD2;
}

.section-1 {
  flex: 80%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #bfd8d2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.bands {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Elle and Belle Design</h1>
  <p1>Bespoke Handmade Headbands and Accessories</p>
</div>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="products">
      <a href="products.html" class="dropdown">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="headbands.html">Headbands</a>
        <a href="earrings.html">Earrings</a>
        <a href="Other.html">Other</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="mainbody">
  <div class="updates">
    <h3>Updates</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="section-1">
    <div class="bands">
      <img src="oliviaband.jpg" alt="Olivia Band" width="330" height="400">
      <img src="goldband.jpg" alt="Gold Band" width="330" height="400">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first issue is that the main-nav is hiding any content that flows outside of it's borders change to:

```
.main-nav ul {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Second is that the menu item you want to snap to needs to have position relative set, this tells any children with position absolute what it's reference container should be

```
li.products {
  position: relative;
}
```

Lastly set the dropdowns position co-ordinates

```
.products:hover .dropdown-content {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    z-index: 0.9;
    height: 5vw;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 20vw;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vw;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    height: 5vw;
}

.main-nav li {
    float: left;
    height: 5vw;
}

.logoimg {
    height: 5vw;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    z-index: 1;
}

.main-nav li a, .dropdown {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.2em 2.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'tenderness';
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    height: 5vw;
    border-bottom: 0.3vw solid transparent;
}

.main-nav li a:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 0.3vw solid whitesmoke;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    min-width: 6vw;
    height: 1.15vw;
}

.main-nav li a:hover:after {
    height: 1.15vw;
    transform: scaleX(1); 
}


li.products {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 5vw;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    min-width: 8vw;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 5vw;
}

.products:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

This is my new code. I have added the bottom border to each li as you can see when the user hovers. However, I am wanting it to align with the bottom of the navigation bar, rather than directly under the text.

I have just put an estimated height in of 1.2vw so it looks just about right, however, it isn't exact and I was just wondering if there was a more precise and not so makeshift way of doing this?

Thanks
Mary

Comment: This would likely be better off posted as a new question at this point.